# How can I decode the address from XDR envelope

Tags: stellar-sdk, javascript-sdk

I am trying to write a page to show all the transaction history of an account, I use `StellarSdk.xdr.TransactionEnvelope.fromXDR(page.records[0].envelope_xdr, 'base64')` to get the transaction envelope, however the source account is encoded with Ed25519.

I tried to use the function below to decode it, it will be shown as `r��)'-�)�sjލC5�B   }�'Z���?��`.

```
function Decodeuint8arr(uint8array) {
    return new TextDecoder("utf8").decode(uint8array);
}
```

What is the correct way to decode the XDR information, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a raw binary form of the public key.
Use `StrKey` encoder to convert the binary key into the string representation:

```js
import {StrKey} from 'stellar-sdk'

function formatPubKey(rawPubKey) {
  return StrKey.encodeEd25519PublicKey(rawPubKey)
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Just a friendly reminder to the others, for calling the StrKey we could directly use `StellarSdk.StrKey.encodeEd25519PublicKey(rawPubKey);`